# Display table field through query using form

Tags: forms, ms-access

Just some background information. My table, (HireHistory) has 50 columns in it (horizontal). I have a Form (HireHistoryForm) which has a 2 text boxes (HistoryMovieID and HistoryCustomerID) and a button (the button runs the query 'HireHistoryQuery')

Here's an excerpt of my data (the CustomerID's are along the top): 
[image: Data]

So what I need is so that if a number is entered into the HistoryCustomerID box, then it displays that column. e.g. if the value entered is '1', then in my query it will show all records from column 1.

If a number is entered into the HistoryMovieID box (e.g. 0001) then it displays all instances of that MovieID for the specific CustomerID's. i.e. In column 1 is the ID's, so for ID=1 it will show "0001 on 19/05/2006" then will go on to find the next instance of '0001' etc.

For the HistoryCustomerID I tried to put this into my 'Field' for the query:

```
=[Forms]![HireHistoryForm]![HistoryCustomerID]
```

But it didn't work. My query just returned a column labelled '10' and the rows were just made up of '10'.

If you could help I'd greatly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense intended (or as little as possible, anyway), but that is a ***horrible*** way to structure your data. You *really* need to restructure it like this:

```
CustomerID  MovieID HireDate
----------  ------- --------
1           0001    19/05/2006
1           0003    20/10/2003  
1           0007    13/08/2003
...     
2           0035    16/08/2012
2           0057    06/10/2012
...
```

If you keep your current data structure then

1. You'll go mad, and
2. It's extremely unlikely that anyone else will go anywhere *near* this problem.

### Edit

Your revised data structure is a *very slight* improvement, but it still works against you. Consider that in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073518/how-to-display-specific-row-in-access) you are essentially asking for a way to "fix" your data structure "on the fly" when you do a query.

The good news is that you can run a bit of VBA code *once* to convert your data structure to something workable. Start by creating your new table, which I'll call "HireHistoryV2"

```
ID         - AutoNumber, Primary Key
CustomerID - Number(Long Integer), Indexed (duplicates OK)
MovieID    - Text(4), Indexed (duplicates OK)
HireDate   - Date/Time, Indexed (duplicates OK)
```

The VBA code to copy your data to the new table would look something like this:

```
Function RestructureHistory()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rstIn As DAO.Recordset, rstOut As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field, a() As String

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rstIn = cdb.OpenRecordset("HireHistory", dbOpenTable)
Set rstOut = cdb.OpenRecordset("HireHistoryV2", dbOpenTable)

Do While Not rstIn.EOF
    For Each fld In rstIn.Fields
        If fld.Name Like "Hire*" Then
            If Not IsNull(fld.Value) Then
                a = Split(fld.Value, " on ", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
                rstOut.AddNew
                rstOut!CustomerID = rstIn!CustomerID
                rstOut!MovieID = a(0)
                rstOut!HireDate = CDate(a(1))
                rstOut.Update
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set fld = Nothing
    rstIn.MoveNext
Loop
rstOut.Close
Set rstOut = Nothing
rstIn.Close
Set rstIn = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
MsgBox "Done!"
End Function
```

**Note:** You appear to be using dd/mm/yyyy date formatting, so ***check the date conversions carefully*** to make sure that they converted properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I've edited my question and it shows how my data is currently structured. Is that still horrible? Because the thing is, I have a LOT of data and it will be really hard for me to turn it into this format.

Is there any way that I could possibly do this? I don't really need to do much else with this data; this is all I really need. So if it's possible to do it without completely re-doing my whole data, that would be a great time-saver!

Comment: Thanks! I just used it and it's perfect! But now if I try to use the LIKE or = function, then when I put in '1' for `CustomerID`, I get my query giving me 11's and 21's with LIKE, and if I use = I don't get anything when I don't put anything in.

Comment: @NightSpy2 I can understand why `LIKE "*1*"` would match `11`, `21`, etc., but I don't really understand what you mean when you say that `=` returns nothing when you "don't put anything in". Whatever mechanism you are using may have to check for the case when you "don't put anything in" (*somewhere...*) and just use `LIKE "*"`, which will match *everything*.

Comment: So for example if I use `="*" & [Forms]![HireHistoryForm]![HistoryMovieID] & "*"` on either one of the fields (or both), I get nothing returned in my query. No matter whether I enter in values or not. I don't really understand what you mean by 'it may have to check for the case'. Do you mean I need something to check whether it is empty, and if it is then it uses `LIKE "*"` to filter the results?

Comment: @NightSpy2 **(1)** `=` is a literal comparison, so the asterisks have no special meaning and nothing will match because you don't have actual asterisks in your `MovieID` values. However, asterisks *do* have special meaning when used with the `LIKE` operator. **(2)** Yes, I was thinking about using something like `IsNull()` to see if the text box is empty, and if so then just using `LIKE "*"` to match all records.