# How to display specific row in Access

Tags: ms-access, row

If I have a table with a Primary key 'ID', and then I have other data in columns, (let's just say for example: Name, Address, PhoneNum) how can I make a query so that it displays the Name, Address and PhoneNum (the whole row) vertically for a specific ID?

If needed I can post a picture trying to explain what I mean.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you just need to display it vertically, or do you need the result for each column to be physically in different rows?

Comment: The latter. So, I need it so that the result from each column for that specific ID is displayed in different rows in my query. :)

Answer (score 1):

For my sample data in a table called [Clients]

```
ID  LastName    FirstName   Email
--  --------    ---------   -----
1   Thompson    Gord        gord@example.com
2   Loblaw      Bob         bob@example.com
3   Kingsley    Hank        hank@example.com
```

the query

```
SELECT "LastName" AS fld, LastName AS val FROM Clients WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT "FirstName" AS fld, FirstName AS val FROM Clients WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT "Email" AS fld, Email AS val FROM Clients WHERE ID=1;
```

returns

```
fld         val
---         ---
LastName    Thompson
FirstName   Gord
Email       gord@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but is it possible to do it somehow for all columns? As I have ~ 100 and it would be a bit of a pain typing it all out. (Might be useful to know that my columns are named "Hire1", "Hire2" etc) :)

Comment: @NightSpy2 See my answer to your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028162/display-table-field-through-query-using-form/16078371#16078371). It appears that you have some issues with the structuring of your data that *really* need to be addressed before you invest too much more time in writing queries and code.

Comment: I see how a problem may arise from this. *Sigh*, If only I knew that these kinds of problems would come up if I structured my data this way! I wasted so much time trying to generate that data. Oh well. See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028162/display-table-field-through-query-using-form). If it is in any way possible, that would save me a load of time, and a lot of tears. Thanks for you help. :)